# $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n \mathrm{Var}[X_i] = 0$. Then $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \mathsf{E} [X_i])\to0$.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ be a probability space. Let $(X_k)_k$ be a sequence of independent random variable with finite second moment. If $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i = 1}^n \mathrm{Var}[X_i] = 0$ then show $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \mathsf{E} [X_i])$ converges to $0$ in probability as $n$ goes to $\infty$.

I am new to probability theory and trying to solve exercises. I am stuck with this question. I believe, I have to use Cheybshev inequality and Borel Contelli lemma but I couldn't figure out exactly how.

Any idea or help is appreciated.

Comment: Is it really $\textrm{Var}[X_k]^\color{red}{2}$, or is it a typo?

Comment: @Snoop I think it is a typo because otherwise it is not true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need Borel Cantelli. Just use wisely the Cheybshev inequality. Let $Y = \frac1n \sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i$, then \begin{align}
\texttt{Var}\left[Y\right] = \frac1{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n \texttt{Var}\left[X_i\right] \to 0
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\texttt P\left[\left|\frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n \left(X_i - \texttt E\left[X_i\right]\right)\right| \ge \varepsilon \right] &= \texttt P\left[\left|Y - \texttt E[Y]\right| \ge \varepsilon \right]\\
&\le \frac{\texttt{Var}[Y]}{\varepsilon^2} \to 0
\end{align}